# IQKeyboardManager is not working in subviews

Tags: ios, uiview, uitextfield, iqkeyboardmanager

I have three `UIView`s in a single `UIViewController`. Each `UIView` contains a `UITextField` . But `IQKeyboardManager` is not showing next and previous arrows as every textfield is in a different view.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: try TPKeyboardAvoiding https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding .You have to add your 3 views in scrollView and subclas your scrollView from TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan , in TPKeyboardAvoiding I faced 2 situations . 1) My views expands as scrollview scrolls . As their height is relative to superview , not fixed . 2)  After disabling the scroll view my view hangs . & in both of the cases the keyboard is hiding the last view which was already under the keyboard .

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan , I Have ScrollView and SubView as UIView and In View a have TextFields, I am Unable to Scroll the ScrollView Automically to TextField. I Tired to Set UiView which is under to ScrollView as IQPreviousNextView. But not Working.But the IQPreviousNextView work in case of Stack View. I am using the IQKeyboardManager

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can make UITextFields/UITextViews container view as IQPreviousNextView. It is designed to handle the situation you are facing. You can find it's demo on repository demo project.[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this only from the Storyboard?  I tried changing the custom class of the container view to IQPreviousNextView to no avail.  When I enable debugging it is only finding one responder sibling despite having two fields.

Comment: Ah, I see now.  The common parent view of all views which contain UITextFields must be of type IQPreviousNextView.  I was only setting the sibling container elements as that class.